# What is the most efficient way to populate a table that contains changes in a dataset using standard SQL?

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table (**table a**) that contains the following fields:

```
customer_id  (varchar)
customer_status (varchar)
segment1_flag  (smallint)
segment2_flag  (smallint)
run_time (datetime)
```

This table is cleared and updated each day. A copy of the data is stored in a history table (**table b**) with the following fields

```
history_ID (varchar)
run_time (datetime)
customer_id  (varchar)
customer_status (varchar)
segment1_flag  (smallint)
segment2_flag  (smallint)
```

I then have a table (**table c**) which contains the changes between the **table a** refresh (i.e if a field value changed between the current upload and the last upload). Table C contains the following fields.

```
 customer_id  (varchar)
 customer_status (varchar)
 segment1_flag  (smallint)
 segment2_flag  (smallint)
 run_time (datetime)
```

This is the SQL I run to update **table c**

```
SELECT  
    sha2(a.CUSTOMER_ID,256),
    A.CUSTOMER_STATUS,
    A.SEGMENT1_FLAG,
    A.SEGMENT2_FLAG,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()      
FROM TABLE_A  as a
LEFT JOIN TABLE C as b
ON a.CUSTOMER_ID = b.CUSTOMER_ID    
WHERE 
B.CUSTOMER_ID IS NULL
OR((
A.CUSTOMER_ID <> B.CUSTOMER_ID OR
A.CUSTOMER_STATUS <> B.CUSTOMER_STATUS OR
A.SEGMENT1_FLAG <> B.SEGMENT1_FLAG OR
A.SEGMENT2_FLAG <> B.SEGMENT2_FLAG) 
AND TO_DATE(B.RUN_DATE) = DATEADD(Day,-1,TO_DATE(A.RUN_DATE)))
```

I need to keep a history of table a and i need to have a table that shows the changes between table refresh. Is this the most efficient way of doing it (3 tables)? Or is there a more efficient method? For context there are around 30 fields in the table (the above is abbreviated) and I am running this in Snowflake but needs to be applicable for other warehouses.

Thanks in advance
Nick

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify the question.

Comment: why do you need table C if you already have a history table ? Can't you query the history table to determine the changes ? Also `EXCEPT` or `MINUS` can compare all the columns at once without you having to chain 30 <> checks.

Comment: I, too, wonder what you need C for, when its data can be determined from A and B. Anyway, as you ask about the SQL standard: In standard SQL you would probably use a trigger to write C everytime A is being written to. If you don't want this, but want to retrieve the delta later, you'd use `MERGE` in standard SQL.

Comment: @GabrielDurac  Table C is required because i have a script that needs to read a table and push the data elsewhere. The script can't run a query, it can only read table c. The desired output is what I currently have in table c - i am just looking at ways to make it more efficient. i.e Could I do it all with just Table B/Table C?

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake, depending on how long you need to keep the history for, you could simply leverage Change Tracking and Time Travel in Snowflake.  At Enterprise or above edition, you can do this for up to 90 days worth of history.  If you need longer than that, you should use Zero-Copy Clones to store older data.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/changes.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-time-travel.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-clone.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your process, just make sure that you create **table a** as a transient table. As this table goes under complete refresh process. Otherwise it will add Fail-safe cost to you.